# How can I draw styrene using xymtex?

Tags: xymtex

How can I draw styrene using xymtex?

[image: styrene]

Comment: Suggest you look at the package chemfig, which is built on top of the Tikz package instead of using xyfig.  For the chemist, you are not required to know anything about tikz, but you do need to know chemistry to understand how to use the package.  Lots of very nice examples.

Comment: Quite apart from the tool chosen, I'd tidy up the angles a bit! Either the phenyl group or the double bond should be angled so everything stays 'ideal'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my first use of the package `xymtex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtex}
\begin{document}
\sbox4{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)(343,502)%
    \put(0,0){\bzdrh[c]{}}%
  \end{picture}%
}
\bzdrv[c]{1==CH=CH$_2$}
\ethylene{1==C;2==C}{1==H;2==H;3==\box4;4==H}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer to your question (and as such, you should accept Heiko's answer), but as R. Schumacher suggested, you can also accomplish this with the newer (and more robust) [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{**6(----(-=[::-60])--)}\qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-=[::-60])-=)}\qquad
\chemfig{**6(----(-CH=[::-90]CH_2)--)}\qquad
\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH=[::-90]CH_2)-=)}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of MWE output for styrene examples]

Comment: You should use `CH_2` instead of `CH2`

Comment: Despite the fact that I also think that `chemfig` is the better choice: this doesn't answer the question at all...

Comment: LionelMANSUY: Thanks.
cgnieder: True. I should have said this to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

XyMTeX supports the (yl) function for nested substitution. 
The following examples show (1) changing font sizes, 
(2) changing formula sizes, (3) changing fonts, 
and (4) selection of basis skeletons (`\bzdrv`, `\bzdrh`, or 
`\tetramethylenei`).

The code adopts the PostScript mode of the XyMTeX system, 
which presumes the processing with dvips(k). 
The other modes commented out are possible to be applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xymtex}%XyMTeX plain
%\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%XyMTeX for PDF ... dvipdfmx ... .pdf
\usepackage{xymtexps}%XyMTeX for PostScript ... dvips(k) ... .ps
\usepackage{txfonts}%Times Roman
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}%Helvetica 95%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\let\substfontsize=\small%changing font size
\bzdrh{2==\ethylene{1==C;2==C}{1==H;2==H;3==(yl);4==H}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\changeunitlength{0.07pt}%changing formula size
\bzdrv{1==\tetramethylenei[b]{1==H;2==C;3==C;4==H}{2==(yl);3==H}}
\bzdrv{1==\tetramethylenei[b]{1==H;4==H}{2==(yl);3==H}} \\
\let\substfont=\sf%changing font: san serif
\tetramethylenei[b]{1==H;2==C;3==C;4==H}{2==\bzdrv[c]{1==(yl)};3==H}
\tetramethylenei[b]{1==H;4==H}{2==\bzdrv[c]{1==(yl)};3==H}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the author of `xymtex` was persuaded to upload a copy to ctan when he had a paper in tugboat.  unfortunately he never followed this up, so (a) the copy on ctan is pathetially old, and (b) the procedure for getting a current version used to change every time i looked.  my advice is to use `chemfig`, as others have suggested.

Comment: The latest version of XyMTeX is available from 
the XyMTeX homepage (http://xymtex.com/): 

  http://xymtex.com/fujitas3/xymtex/indexe.html

Comment: For further information on topics discussed once in Web, 
please see XyMTeX-tips of the XyMTeX homepage (http://xymtex.com/): 

http://xymtex.com/fujitas3/xymtex-tips/indexe.html

The present topic has been deposited as 130204a.pdf.

Comment: I believe that the selection of tools for drawing chemical structures depends on what one is aiming at now and in the future. XyMTeX is based on the XyM notation (S. Fujita and N. Tanaka, J. Chem. Inf. Comput. Sci., 39, 903-914 (1999)), which has been extended into a markup language named XyMML (XyM markup language, S. Fujita, J. Chem. Inf. Comput. Sci., 39, 915-927 (1999)).

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer from @cfair this code will draw "exactly" your representation of the styrene molecule, including the annotation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemname{\chemfig{C(-[::120]H)(-[::-120]H)=C(-[::60]H)(-[::-60]**6(------))}}
    {\textbf{Styrene}}
\end{document}
```

There is an option to control the length of the bonds

[image: styrene molecule]